# Accessing network files using authentication in .NET

Tags: c#, .net, windows, authentication, authorization

How can I get a directory listing of files in a remote server that requires authentication?

I tried something like this, but `GetFiles` doesn't return any files.

```
        DirectoryInfo dir = new DirectoryInfo(path);
        foreach (FileInfo f in dir.GetFiles("*.exe"))
        {
            string name = f.Name;
            long size = f.Length;
            DateTime creationTime = f.CreationTime;
            Console.WriteLine("{0,-12:N0} {1,-20:g} {2}", size,
                creationTime, name);
        }
```

Also, running `dir \\<computer name>\files location` gives me an Access denied error.

So, how do I authenticate myself using .NET or command line?

Thanks.

Comment: "authenticate myself..." is sort of strange request. What account you run your code under if it is not your account?

Comment: @AlexeiLevenkov, let's say that the remove machine requires me to enter certain credentials to view a folder. How do I do that programatically?

Comment: It is called "imeprsonation". Check out [WindowsIdentity.Impersonate]](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/w070t6ka%28v=vs.110%29.aspx) and search for similar questions.